# select query joining two tables on a range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

Table A with columns

```
name | tag | price | ref
```

and Table B with columns:

```
id | time | min_ref | max_ref
```

I want to make the following query, take `all` columns from table A and columns `id` and `time` from Table B, combining rows in such a way that particular row from A is merged with a row from B if value `ref` from A is in the range `(min_ref, max_ref)`. Example:

```
A
name | tag | price | ref
A    | aaa | 78    | 456
B    | bbb | 19    | 123
C    | ccc | 5     | 789

B

id | time       | min_ref | max_ref
0  | 26-01-2019 | 100     | 150
1  | 27-01-2019 | 450     | 525
2  | 25-01-2019 | 785     | 800
```

the query should return:

```
name | tag | price | ref | id | time 
A    | aaa | 78    | 456 | 1  | 27-01-2019
B    | bbb | 19    | 123 | 0  | 26-01-2019
C    | ccc | 5     | 789 | 2  | 25-01-2019
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation [`(min_ref, max_ref)` for *ranges* signifies *exclusive* bounds](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY). Would be `[min_ref, max_ref]` for *inclusive*.

So:

```
select a.*, b.id, b.time
from   a
join   b on a.ref > b.min_ref
        and a.ref < b.max_ref;
```

The [`BETWEEN` predicate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) treats all bounds as *inclusive*.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a `join`:

```
select a.*, b.id, b.time
from a join
     b
     on a.ref between b.min_ref and b.max_ref;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a `JOIN` which combines rows from the two tables with an appropriate criteria. For instance:

```sql
SELECT a.name, a.tag, a.price, a.ref, b.id, bi.time
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.min_ref <= a.ref AND b.max_ref >= a.ref
```

The `INNER JOIN` finds matching rows from the two tables, `ON` a specified criteria. In this case, the criteria is that `a.ref` is between `b.min_ref` and `b.max_ref`.

You can also use the sql [`BETWEEN` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) to simplify the conditionals:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.ref BETWEEN b.min_ref AND b.max_ref
```

Comment: Hi! While this may provide a solution to OP's question, code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. It is important for OP to understand *why* this is a solution as it will help them more in the long run and be more beneficial for future visitors of the site. Thanks!